# JavaScript/NodeJS - Mongo DB gets Dates with offsets (timezone)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, backbone.js

We are loading Dates from a Mongo database. It seems that Mongo saves everything in UTC, but when JS creates Date objects (for display this dates) it adds/substracts the timezone offset. The result is, for example:

- If I save the date "2013-06-20 01:00:00"
- The date will be later auto-completed in a form as "2013-06-19 22:00:00" (Example for Argentina Time Zone UTC-03:00), and if the user saves that form without changing the date, the date will be saved with that wrong time.
- Worst that that, the next save will substracts 3 hours MORE, and so on!

As you see, I can get even different DAYS that the ones I wanted to save.
I saw a few similar cases but nothing with this same technologies, I'm using Nodejs, MongoDB and Backbone. Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
    parse: function(response) {
       var dateStart = new Date(response.time.start);
       var offset = dateStart.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
       response.time.start = new Date(dateStart.valueOf() + offset);
       return response;
    }
```

But it's really ugly and I have to do it every time I instantiate a new Date()

Anybody know a nice way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So sadly when you instantiate a Date object in a web browser, it will be in the browser's local time zone. Sometimes this helps, sometimes not. You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) `moment.utc(myDate)` to handle this and keep things in UTC. In general I highly recommend moment.js for your go-to Swiss Army knife of date related code.

Another approach would be to change your client to not submit fields to the server unless their value has truly changed.

Comment: i am struggling with a similar problem however the trick for me is when i use a string object which momentjs creates for me it seems to store the field in mongodb as a string and not the ISODate('.....') format. If i use javascript Date() object it mongo pics up that it is a date and stores it as ISODate. So the question is how do you get mongo to read a momentjs date to be a date..

Comment: Use the `toDate()` function on the moment instance to get back to a regular javascript Date instance.